# Constructing (a Type of) Multi-party Transaction

Tags: transactions

I am looking to construct a raw transaction with the following properties:

- n addresses (call them a) input at least b BTC each.
- n addresses (call them a') may claim up to b BTC each as output.
- No output may be claimed unless every output may be claimed.

I have made a sketch of what I think the tx should look like. It's just an extension of a standard address tx:

(For each address i in a)

```
Input: 

    Previous tx: <some tx with an output >= b that i may claim>
    Index: <an appropriate index from the above txn>
    scriptSig: <signature from i> <public key for i>
```

(For each address i in a')

```
Output: 

    Value: <b>
    scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <hash of i's public key> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

Does this appear correct?